# Flask app does not work in some directories

Tags: python, flask

I've followed a tutorial to setup a hello world flask app.

https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world

Lo and behold, after doing `export FLASK_APP=microblog.py` and `flask run` it works great.

But then when I move that mini project into another directory inside of another already existing python project and do the exact same thing, it doesn't work.  I get...

```
Error: Failed to find Flask application or factory in module "microblog". Use "FLASK_APP=microblog:name to specify one.
```

Which of course I've done.  Or...

```
Error: Could not import "microblog".
```

Seemingly depending where I move the folder.  What could be causes of conflict here?  The error messages don't give me a lot of ideas.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just use an absolute path `export FLASK_APP=/path/to/microblog.py` after you have moved it

Comment: @pissall Thank you!  You could post that as an answer if you'd like, it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an absolute path:

```
export FLASK_APP=/path/to/microblog.py
```